How to Make VSCode Autocomplete Future<void> onLoad() Instead of FutureOr<void> onLoad()
Related: What exactly is FutureOr<void> onLoad?
When I try to write onLoad in VSCode, it autocompletes as FutureOr<void> onLoad().
However, I want it to autocomplete as Future<void> onLoad().
How can I configure VSCode to suggest Future<void> onLoad() instead?
Most Flutter Flame sample code online uses Future<void> onLoad(),
For example: https://docs.flame-engine.org/latest/flame/game.html

 @override
 Future<void> onLoad() async {
   sprite = await Sprite.load('crate.png');
 }



it autocompletes FutureOr since it is the returned value of Component.onLoad method

either use a snippet instead or create a custom base widget with more specific onLoad return type

You can't, not directly at least, since FutureOr<void> is what the super class specifies as its method signature return type. As suggested you can create a VSCode snippet for it though.
